# Facebook API share response not giving any details

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

```
                FB.ui({
                method: 'feed',
                type: 'video',
                caption: text,
                link: url,
                description: text,
                source: url,
                picture: pictureEncode
            }, function(response){
                if (response && !response.error_code) {
                    console.log("OK: "+JSON.stringify(response));
                } else {
                    console.log("Not OK: "+JSON.stringify(response));
                }
            });
```

I tried to share YouTube video from my and it's working. But I need to identify is that user canceled the video share or not. In the response I'm not getting any useful values.They are like this below.

> constructor
>   :
>   function Object()
>   hasOwnProperty
>   :
>   function hasOwnProperty()
>   isPrototypeOf
>   :
>   function isPrototypeOf()
>   propertyIsEnumerable
>   :
>   function propertyIsEnumerable()
>   toLocaleString
>   :
>   function toLocaleString()
>   toString
>   :
>   function toString()
>   valueOf
>   :
>   function valueOf()
>   **defineGetter**
>   :
>   function **defineGetter**()
>   **defineSetter**
>   :
>   function **defineSetter**()
>   **lookupGetter**
>   :
>   function **lookupGetter**()
>   **lookupSetter**
>   :
>   function **lookupSetter**()
>   get **proto**
>   :
>   function **proto**()
>   set **proto**
>   :
>   function **proto**()

So help me out with this to find out this problem. thank you

Comment: see my answer below. may i ask why you need to know if he canceled? i added some important info about that in my answer.

Comment: I wanted to get callback is that user shared the video or he canceled it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog

Take a look at the response parameter, there is an important text:

> ...post_id requires your app to have publish_actions granted, and for
>   the user to share to their timeline or a group.

The `post_id` will only be in the response after sharing if the user authorized the App with `publish_actions`.

---

Make sure you read the platform policy too, you are not allowed to incentivize users to share something on their wall (reward, gate content):

> 4.5 Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on
>   your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other
>   actions.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. I find out that the I need to get  "publish_actions" from user for the app. But it won't be easy to get approve Facebook side  if I use publish_actions. So I find out another way to do it. I used another field called display:'popup', . If user canceled or closed that popup there  will be a undefined callback and if user shared that video there will be a response. Thank you again